# Exception parameter of uni-catch may be effectively final?

Tags: java, javadoc, java-8

A statement from [The Java® Language Specification:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4)

> An exception parameter of a *uni-catch* clause is never implicitly
> declared `final`, but may be effectively final.

What does ***may be*** implies here. Please explain with example.

Comment: I think you should be looking at the definition of effectively final.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I google and found that variables which are not changed are effectively final, but when I read `Java doc` I found above statement, I got confused with, exception parameter `may be` effectively final for `uni-catch` block. I was not able to picturise what does this mean.

Comment: It *may be* effectively final in the sense that any parameter may be effectively final.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The JLS8 states in section [4.12.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4):

> A local variable or a method, constructor, lambda, or exception parameter is effectively final if it is not declared final but it never occurs as the left hand operand of an assignment operator (§15.26) or as the operand of a prefix or postfix increment or decrement operator (§15.14, §15.15).

In the following example, the variable `e` is *effective final*. That means it can be used in *lambda expressions* and *anonymous inner classes*:

```
try {
    throw new RuntimeException("foobar");
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
    Runnable r = () -> { System.out.println(e); };
    r.run();
}
```

In the following example, the variable `e` is **not** *effective final*, because there is an assignment to that variable. That means, it can not be used within *lambda expressions* and *anonymous inner classes*:

```
try {
    throw new RuntimeException("foo");
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
    e = new RuntimeException("bar", e);
    Runnable r = () -> { System.out.println(e); }; // ERRROR
    r.run();
}
```